# Can two infiniband ports be bridged together to make a switch?

Tags: infiniband

I have 3 machines with infiniband cards, two with single ports and one with two ports. I do not own any switches. I have my network setup such that the computer with 2 ports, running Linux, routes between the other two hosts in different IP subnets. Is it possible to bridge these two ports so that all 3 hosts are on the same IP subnet as if the 2 ports were a switch?

Comment: If they behave as Ethernet devices the regular bridging tools might work, I.e. `brctl addbr br0 ; brctl addif br0 ib0 ; brctl addif br0 ib1 ; ip link set br0 up`

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that. The ib interfaces do not use Ethernet as a layer 2 protoco so the standard bridging stack doesn't work on them.

Comment: You might be able to route IPoIB traffic between the two ports, but I don't think you can forward RDMA traffic or identify these ports as a switch to the SM.

Comment: Yeah at the moment I just have routing rules and that actually works quite well, but I would like it to be simpler. My guess is that this is possible to bridge RDMA etc from a technical perspective but nothing like this is implemented in the IB stack.